# Cant I use subset() in Function() after generating data frame with ddplyr

Tags: r

This is an assignment question everybody in my class solved it through split,apply I want to use different approach and used ddplyr and got stuck.
Here I have to generate a function `best("State","Outcome")`, o/p is Hospital name with lowest Mortality rate in the state entered.
eg-`best("TX","heart failure")` o/p-"CYPRESS"

MYCODE-

In the above steps Ihave read the file & subsetted the desired columns in data1

```
library(plyr)
data2 <- ddply(data1,.(State, Hospital.Name), 
               summarise, Heart.Attack=min(as.numeric(HA,na.rm=TRUE)))
data3 <- data2[complete.cases(data2),]
best <- function(State,outcome)
{
  if(! State %in% data3$State) {
    stop("invalid state") 
  } else if(State %in% data3$State && outcome == "Heart Attack") {
    data4 <- subset(data3, State %in% data3$State, select=c(Hospital.Name))
    return(nrow(data4))
  }
}
```

Here when I am trying to return only those `Hospitalnames` which are in the entered function I am getting all the hospital names, If I assign the value manually then I get the correct no. of rows. I cant understand why its not taking value directly from function `State%in%data3$State`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd suggest you refrain from phrases like "Urgent" and "PLS help" - they are frowned upon and will usually result in your question getting downvoted or ignored.

Comment: @user3595186 I have improved the formatting of the code a bit: added spaces to make it less of a wall of text, use `{}` for each `if`statement.

Comment: you could do, `data3$State==State` or invert your condition as `data3$State %in% State` but more importantly see that you do not violate honor code of this Coursera course. And its better to engage in Coursera forums for such assignment questions

Comment: Thanks@Vivek ,I have done both the suggested things,but I am not getting my answer,I have asked the same questions on forums also but no one is able to answer ....thats the reason I asked here...I can also use normal methods but I want to know Why I am not getting my answer through this..

Comment: can you post your output so that we know the issue, and use `dput(data)` and post it as well, where data is your input data.frame

Comment: with the above code.
data3$State %in% State
> best("AK","Heart Attack")
[1] 2706

If I assign manually
data3$State=='AK'
> best("AK","Heart Attack")
[1] 5

Answer (score 0):

Well the error resolved...

I introduced empty character vector in loop,assigned the State value to it and then compared.